# Size of an empty database

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, database-size

Continuing with my [school-project](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/estimate-a-database-size), now I have to estimate the size of the database from here to 5 years. They give me a formula, so, in that formula, one of the values is the size of the empty database (when it is created, and doesn't have any tables, index, etc.).

For example, for MySQL, I found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/innodb-configuration.html) that it is 10 MB.

But, for Oracle, what is the size?

I don't have Oracle or any RDBMS to make queries, it is just a work of research. I've googled a little, but I haven't found for Oracle.

Any version of Oracle (9 or later) is okay.

Comment: "I don't have Oracle or any RDBMS to make queries" why not? How will you test any answer given here if you have no database to run it on? Here are some [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) including developer and express editions.

Comment: because it's a researching homework. It's an aproximation - it's not real. It's to understand the concept of estimation on a project. They give us a project, and we have to make a design and choose a RDBMS, and present the documentation (as a licitation). We had choose Oracle (for the size of the project) but we don't have Oracle to test the design in querys, about the space

Comment: Well I highly recommend testing anything you propose whether it is theoretical or not because a) you are much less likely to submit something wrong, and b) you will learn a good deal more in the process - isn't that the real purpose of homework, to learn?

Comment: I guess you're right - The project is to emulate the instance since the idea of a project, to the presentation in a licitation. It's only documentation, I don't know if in the reality the design of paper is really created and checked and tested - that won't happen when the project is accepted ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, are you using "database" in the Oracle sense of the term?  Or are you using it in the sense that other database vendors (such as SQL Server or MySQL) use the term?

If you are using "database" in the Oracle sense, that would be the size of the `SYSTEM` and `SYSAUX` tablespaces at a minimum and would possibly include the size of the `UNDO` and `TEMP` tablespaces.  On a small laptop system, that's probably on the order of 2 - 3 GB but it could be much bigger.

If you are using "database" in the sense that other database vendors use it, that's what Oracle calls a schema.  An empty schema (a schema with no objects), by definition, consumes 0 bytes of storage.  That's because space is allocated to tablespaces which are independent of schemas-- a single schema can have objects in many different tablespaces, a single tablespace can have objects owned by many different schemas, and a single object (if you're using partitioning) can be spread across multiple tablespaces.

Comment: amm, you got me here ! I had never used Oracle - so I'm not sure about the answer. I guess it will be in the Oracle sense. I think I will have to ask about that. Anyway, you give both answers - Thanks !